# Is y[n] = x^2[n] linear?

Tags: signal-processing

I'm confused with y[n] = x^2[n] is a parabola which is not linear, but the concept of linearity says that if the input is 0 then the output should be zero.

Can anyone explain?
Thanks

Comment: Lots of function passes through the origo, but few of them are linear function (polynomial functions with degree one or zero).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Converse of a true statement is not necessarily true.

There is a Logical difference between, if the function is linear (and for this I'm assuming you mean additive homogeneity), then f(0)=0, and its converse being true. That is, if f(0)=0 does not necessarily mean it is linear.

Only the contrapositive  must be true: That if f(0) != 0, then it is not linear.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converse_(logic)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearity

Comment: oh okay, i did solve the problem so yes it satisfies aditivity and homogeneity so its linear. thanks!

Comment: btw, your function I'm assuming really should be:
y[n] = x[n] ^ 2
so to test for linearity you would do something like
y[1] = 1^2 = 1, 
y[2] = 2^2 = 4, 
y[1 + 2] =9, 
but 9 != 4+1
 --  
so it is non linear, proof by counter example

Answer (score 1):

> In common usage, linearity refers to a mathematical relationship or function that can be graphically represented as a straight line

Comment: my professor said "A discrete time system is linear if and only if zero input produces zero output and a linear combination of inputs produces a linear combination of outputs"

Comment: @masaldana2 I'm not really familiar with discrete time systems, but the last part of the sentence "and a linear combination....." gives you the clue. If you linearly increase the input value, the output should increase (or decrease) linearly. x^n where n>1 increases exponentially.